# AlphaVantage - List of all tickers on an Exchange

Tags: api, stockquotes

I recently started exploring Alpha Vantage. I was wondering if there is an endpoint which would list all the tickers being traded on an exchange.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 14):

Check out the alpha vantage documentation at
https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/

Go to Listing and Delisting Status

> Examples To ensure optimal API response time, this endpoint uses the
> CSV format which is more memory-efficient than JSON.
>
> Querying all active stocks as of the latest trading day:
> https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=LISTING_STATUS&apikey=demo
>
> Querying all delisted stocks as of 2014-07-10:
> https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=LISTING_STATUS&date=2014-07-10&state=delisted&apikey=demo

Comment: FYI this only applies to US stocks.